# WEKA variables workspace

Tags: variables, weka, workspace

I'm looking for a way to visualize weka variables as it happens using Matlab , R , Python , ecc.

Do you know anyone?

Thanks!

Actually I researched in the web without results.

Could be helpful to run weka in python or Matlab?

Comment: Please provide a pseudo code example to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I'm using  knowledgeflow , the problem is not inerent to a specific code but to the plaftorm itself.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get access to intermediate results? Just for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes it could be too. In reality I need to follow the algorithm of some filter like Partition Membership and classifier like J48 to see how does it work and why they return some results. I need to integrate it with Matlab and to adapt this flow to my task and to control the feasibility of the entire process. I could break it too in the explorer but the problem remain the same.

Comment: Unless you use a Java debugger from an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA, Java classes will be black boxes: you call a method and you get a result (eg present a data row to a trained classifier and get back a prediction), you don't get any insights (eg why did it make that particular decision).

Comment: In debugging mode I can see them but it's difficult to understand how they are organized ( not the Matlab array whit rows and columns) , and there's not a gui function to plot them. Visualization is not implemented.